# How to use the Firebase refreshToken to reauthenticate?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I use the JS library call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` and get back a `User` object. The `User` object contains a [`refreshToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#refreshToken).

I use `curl 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/auth-example.json?auth=TOKEN'` to make calls to Firebase.

The token will eventually expire. In order to make it look like the application (`iOS` and `macOS`) has persistent login, I want to refresh the token, how do I do that with using either the `REST` or `JS` library? I can't find any calls in the documentation that allow me to use the `refreshToken` to get a new `token`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

** **UPDATE** ** this is also now documented in Firebase REST docs under `Exchange a refresh token for an ID token` section:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token

---

Currently the only way I found to do this is here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/reference/securetoken/rest/v1/token

You must make an HTTP request:

`POST` `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=YOUR_KEY`

Where `YOUR_KEY` can be found in the [Google developers console > API Manager > Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). It's under the `API Keys` section.

Make sure request body is structured in the following format:

`grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN`

Where `REFRESH_TOKEN` is the refresh token from Firebase user object when they signed in.

You must set the header `Content-Type: application/json` or you will get errors (e.g. "MISSING_GRANT_TYPE").

The `POST` call will return a new `idToken` (used to be called `access_token`)

Comment: Should this request work for refreshing Gmail API's token? @kgaidis

Comment: @ArtStyle I am not familiar with Gmail API, so I don't know

Comment: This works but unfortunately does not trigger firebase's [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onIdTokenChanged) listener... I feel it should

Comment: I am using the same way and i am getting the id_token. But when i try to fetch values from the DB using the id_token , i get an error saying 'permission denied'.

Comment: how to use the obtained data to set the new token?

Comment: Will the new, google-identity token be invalidated if the firebase user is deleted or invalidated? @kgaidis

Comment: I got 403 (Permission denied) error when I do this. Can I call this API from web client javascript ?

Comment: `access_token` = `id_token`

Comment: Im using Restrict keys for requests to the specified websites. But If add the ```https://securetoken.googleapis.com```  to my restricted list I'm not able to call the API and  I have to remove all other restricted URLs to make a call. In that case, my key would be accessible for every address. Any suggestion?

Comment: thanks so much you made my day, I wish I could have voted a 100 times. My app kept on yelling token expired throughout development, till you came to my aid

Comment: For me, it did not work with `Content-type: application/json` and I had to go back to the old `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 75):

When you make call from a browser `.getIdToken(true)` will automatically refresh your token. Make call like this:

Namespaced / compat API (v8)

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/ forceRefresh / true)
  .then(function(idToken) {
    
  }).catch(function(error) {

});
```

More info
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken

Modular API (v9+)

```js
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'
auth = getAuth()

auth.currentUser.getIdToken(/ forceRefresh / true)
  .then(function(idToken) {
    
  }).catch(function(error) {

});
```

More info
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usergetidtoken

Comment: Wouldn't currentUser be NULL on a fresh launch of an app? I don't know how it is on a regular browser, but I do not store any cookies or local data. I only store the refreshToken and anything else that I specifically need.

Comment: Login is needed to be performed first to use that code. If you use sign in with firebase it should work.

Comment: This! But `.getToken` is deprecated now, you must use `.getIdToken`.

Comment: I got 403 (Permission denied error) even though currentUser is not null (i.e. the user was signed in). Do you know the reason ?

Comment: @TakamitsuMizutori I had the same issue, the token couldn't be refreshed. I solved it by enabling the Token Service API for my Google API key.

Comment: @Louis Ameline It works!  Never thought about the API key. Thank you so much

Comment: @stevehs17 Could you please add your sources, and let everyone know why you think this is wrong? Did you experience this yourself, or is this something that you saw written in the official doc? Thanks

Comment: @Gunee My apologies, but I now think my previous comment (which I will delete) was wrong: getIdToken() always returns a valid token. This is based on my personal experience using that function in a React Native app. (Thank you for calling my attention to my incorrect comment.)

Comment: I'm writing this for nodejs. When app restarts there is no user object, how can i reauthenticate?

Answer (score 16):

I guess most people here are looking for a way to persist their authentication not in a browser but e.g. on a node backend. Turns out there actually is a way to do this:

1. Trade the refresh-token for an access-token (using google's public api)
2. Trade the access-token for a custom-token (using a firebase-function, see below)
3. Login with custom-token

Here's the essence of the code:

```js
const requestP = require('request-promise');
const fsP = require('fs').promises;

const refreshToken = await fsP.readFile('./refresh_token.txt');
const res = await requestP.post({
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  url: 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=' + firebaseConf.apiKey,
  body: 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refreshToken,
  json: true
});
const customToken = await requestP.post({
  headers: {'content-type': 'text/plain'},
  url: 'https://<yourFirebaseApp>.cloudfunctions.net/createCustomToken',
  body: {token: res.access_token},
  json: true
});
await firebaseApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
```

And the firebase function:

```js
export const createCustomToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  try {
      const token = JSON.parse(request.body).token;
      const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
      const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(decodedToken.uid);
      response.send(customToken);
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      response.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: In my case the custom token expires after one hour, what did you do to solve that?

Comment: I just read your answer again, I guess what I need to persist is the refresh token and not the custom token. You are continuously creating custom tokens.

Comment: Yes, you should store the refresh-token, like:


firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user) {
  fs.writeFileSync('./refresh_token.txt', refreshToken);
 }
});

Comment: but the refresh token changes from one user to the other, how do you save it in a text file?

Comment: is this safe to the public to create custom tokens from refresh tokens?

Comment: to avoid any confliction you should replace 'const res = await requestP.post' with 'const anotherRes = await requestP.post' if you have another res inside the same function

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData['uid'] + " is logged with token" + authData['ie']);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
}
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

Event `onAuth` will be called on page refresh, if user was logged out `authData` will be null, else not. You can find token  in `authdata['ie']`. In the screenshot bellow I have printed the token after auth and authdata object, how you can see authData['ie'] and token are similar.

[image: authdata.ie and token]