# How to persist Google auth Firebase session in React Native?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-oauth

I'm developing an Expo React Native application using Google auth with a Firebase integration, I want to know how can I persist the auth session of a user even after one hour, I'm using the following code to store the `accessToken` in local storage and login the user without asking for sign in again, this is working fine but after one hour the `accessToken` is refeshed so the previous one doesn't work anymore and the user has to sign in again.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUserLoggedIn = async () => {
      const googleAccessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('googleAccessToken');
      console.log(googleAccessToken);
      if (googleAccessToken) {
        const auth = getAuth();
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, googleAccessToken);
        try {
          const userCredential = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
          setCurrentUser(userCredential.user!);
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      } else {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      }
    };
```

Is there a way to persist the session even after one hour? I've heard about `onAuthStateChanged` but honestly I'm not sure how to implemented in my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [Supported types of Auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was talking about persistence even after the access token is expired after one hour, how can I re-authenticate the user automatically without asking it to do it manually

Comment: Also, see: [How to persist user after Firebase Token expired in 1 hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58586999/22152755)