# Firebase refresh token from Firebase ID token

Tags: firebase, rest, curl, flutter, firebase-authentication

I know the Firebase ID token can be used to act on behalf of the user. But the token expires after 1hr. 
To fix this, the documentation and this post [How to use the Firebase refreshToken to reauthenticate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233687/how-to-use-the-firebase-refreshtoken-to-reauthenticate) you can supposedly re-authenticate using the REST command here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

I cannot get this to work. Here is the Android Flutter code to print the token on logcat

```java
FirebaseAuth.instance;.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        user.getIdToken(refresh: true).then((IdTokenResult token) {
             dbg.log('firebase TOKEN ' + token.token );
             dbg.log('firebase TOKEN authtime ' + token.authTime.toIso8601String() );
             dbg.log('firebase TOKEN expiration ' + token.expirationTime.toIso8601String() );
             dbg.log('firebase TOKEN issued at ' + token.issuedAtTime.toIso8601String() );
        });
    }
}).catchError((e) {
    dbg.log('fetch user ERROR: ' + e.toString());
});
```

verify that the token does work you can add it to curl:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

TOKEN=<your token>

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your project>/databases/<your databases> | jq
```

This works. But, when I try to get a refresh token :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

TOKEN=<your token>
WEB_API_KEY=<your web api key>

REFRESH_URL=https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=${WEB_API_KEY}

ARGS='{"token":"'${TOKEN}'","returnSecureToken":true}'

echo $ARGS | jq

curl ${REFRESH_URL}  \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary ${ARGS} | jq
```

I get the following error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I missing a step ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm with the same problem. I got the idToken after google sign in, but I need the refreshToken !

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ended up going a different route for my project all together