# Firebase auth getIdToken returns No record corresponding to this identifier

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Environment
Xcode version: 12.5.1
Firebase SDK version: 6.23.0
Installation method: CocoaPods
Firebase Component: Auth

I'm having a problem when trying to getIdToken it returns the following error message: **There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.**
But the user exists in firebase.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Register a new user in firebase.
2. Validate the user using custom token generated by endpoint.
3. Wait for token expiration and try to get the new token
4. The firebase auth returns: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted. But the user exists.

SignIn:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            let user = authResult?.user
            
            completionHandler(user, nil)
}
```

Retrieves the firebase token:

```
func getIdTokenFromFirebase(authStep: NewRelicAuthenticationStep, expiresAt: Date?, completion: @escaping (_ succeeded: Bool, _ refreshToken: String?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            //Retrieves the Firebase authentication token, possibly refreshing it if it has expired.
            user.getIDToken(completion: { (token, error) in
                if let fbToken = token {
                    completion(true, fbToken, nil)
                }
                
                if let fbError = error {
                    completion(false, nil, fbError)
                }
            })
        } else {
            completion(false, nil, nil)
        }
}
```

The firebase returns in **user.getIDToken** the following error:
There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

I'd like to know what's the cause of this error.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show all relevant code.

Comment: Show how you log in and return a token from firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question with the code.

Comment: @ElTomato  I updated the question with the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the Firebase refreshToken to reauthenticate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233687/how-to-use-the-firebase-refreshtoken-to-reauthenticate) (not Swift, but it may be about the same situation)

Comment: "Wait for token expiration and try to get the new token"  Then use `getIDTokenForcingRefresh(bool)`.

Comment: Thank you @ElTomato I applied the getIDTokenForcingRefresh(bool) and it worked.