# Firebase auth - Invalid id_token in IdP response: id token is not issued by Google

Tags: firebase, google-api

I am using the `refresh_token` to get a new id token as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38284384

kgaidis and yevgen suggest two different methods. I am able to successfully use the `refresh_token` to get a new `id_token` using both methods, however, attempting to use the new `id_token` that I receive, I am seeing the following error:

`Invalid id_token in IdP response: id token is not issued by Google.`

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm having the same issue where I have a refresh token and I'm getting a new id_token from the http request, but firebase's signInWithCredential doesn't think the id_token is issued by Google.