# Firebase admin SDK (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using the Google Admin SDK on my node server to create custom token's that a client can use for authentication like so:

```
const uid = 'some-uid';

getAuth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

These tokens expire after an hour...

What is a good way for the client to refresh this token so they can continue using the app without a hiccup? Looking for any suggestions!

I tried looking for some documentation around Refresh tokens or something a like and I've found nothing so far. The only thing I can think of is getting my app to call this endpoint every time it becomes active. But I am looking for a better way to solve this issue.

Comment: lot of info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233687/how-to-use-the-firebase-refreshtoken-to-reauthenticate

Comment: Beauty - thank you. Going to try to implement and see if it solves the problem. Will mark as answered shortly if it works.